# Dynamic url redirect issue

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have dynamic working url

http://filertionline.in/rti/file-rti-online-village.php?village=bela&block=nanpur&district=sitamarhi&state=bihar

I want to redirect is as

https://filertionline.in/rti/rti-in-bihar/rti-in-sitamarhi/rti-in-nanpur/rti-in-bela

I have write url redirect rule but its not working

```
RewriteRule ^rti/rti-in-([^/]*)/rti-in-([^/]*)/rti-in-([^/]*)/rti-in-([^/]*)\ rti/file-rti-online-village.php?village=$1&block=$2&district=$3&state=$4 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
^rti/rti-in-([^/]*)/rti-in-([^/]*)/rti-in-([^/]*)/rti-in-([^/]*)\
                                                                ^
```

Remove that trailing `\`, it makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: Even not working after removing training \ .

.htaccess is in root and php file is in /rti/rti/file-rti-online-village.php

Comment: Please be more specific, “not working” is not a helpful problem description. When I take that regular expression to https://regex101.com/#python, and use `rti/rti-in-bihar/rti-in-sitamarhi/rti-in-nanpur/rti-in-bela` as test string, then it shows that it matches the parts `bihar`, `sitamarhi`, `nanpur` and `bela`

Comment: _“.htaccess is in root and php file is in /rti/rti/file-rti-online-village.php”_ – but your RewriteRule tries to rewrite to `rti/file-rti-online-village.php?…` – so maybe you just specified the path wrong?

Comment: This rule is working 
RedirectMatch 301 rti/rti-in-(.*)/rti-in-(.*)/rti-in-(.*)/rti-in-(.*) /rti/file-rti-online-village.php?state=$1&district=$2&block=$3&village=$4

It shows URL as : 
https://filertionline.in/rti/file-rti-online-village.php?state=bihar&district=sitamarhi&block=nanpur&village=bela

But I want seo rule ..... as
When applying above rule I get page not fount 404 eror
https://filertionline.in/rti/rti-in-bihar/rti-in-sitamarhi/rti-in-nanpur/rti-in-bela